# Different background colors for the text in PDF

Tags: pdftex

I want to define three different light background colors. I want to define them in the preamble and would like to use them in the running code.

My code:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{r1}{ForestGreen}
\colorlet{r2}{RubineRed}
\colorlet{r3}{RoyalPurple}

 \textcolor{r1}{Forestgreen}. \textcolor{r2}{RubineRed}
 It successfully changes the text color to my defined colors. 
 But this is not what I wanted. I want to change the text background color.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be happy to delete this but perhaps this can help clarifying the question at least. This defines a command, `\Hl`, which takes an optional argument. If left empty, the previous highlight color gets used, otherwise a new color comes into play. Of course, one can vary this as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\colorlet{r1}{ForestGreen}
\colorlet{r2}{RubineRed}
\colorlet{r3}{RoyalPurple}

\newcommand{\Hl}[2][\empty]{%
  \ifx#1\empty
  \else
    \colorlet{myhlcolor}{#1}%
    \sethlcolor{myhlcolor}%
  \fi
  \hl{#2}}

\begin{document}
\Hl{Quack} \Hl[r1!20]{Blub} \Hl[r2!50]{Pft} \Hl{Meow} \Hl[r3!30]{Pffft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason that execution of this code taking too long.

Comment: @Mainland On my 6 years old MacBook pro it takes 0.832s to compile if I uses `pdflatex` on an updated TeXLive2020 installation. `lualatex` takes about twice as much. (Did you by chance forget to copy `\end{document}`?)

Comment: You were correct. I accidentally deleted \begin{document}. Now it is corrected. How to use light version background colors here?

Comment: @Mainland You can use e.g. `\Hl[r1!20]{Blub} `. I had to slightly modify the code to make this work.

Comment: I have to highlight the background color so many times in my document. Can't we define it in the preamble? For example, `\colorlet{r3}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}`. Moreover, `\Hl[r1]{Blub}` looks good rather `\Hl[r1!20]{Blub}`.

Comment: @Mainland Of course. I thought you were asking how to mix the colors on the spot. Of course, `\colorlet{r3}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}` won't work, it has to be `\definecolor{r3}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}`.

Comment: Yes It worked. Thanks a ton. How to define your code `[r1!20] ` in the preamble? `\definecolor{r1}[r1!20]` is this correct?

Comment: @Mainland It has to be `\colorlet{r11}{ForestGreen!20}` or `\colorlet{r1}{ForestGreen}
\colorlet{r11}{r1!20}`.

Comment: Thanks. I have no more questions. You solved my big problem without me going to installs the packages stuff that I do not know how to do.

Comment: Are the `%`s necessary?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the soul package for highlighting. But it isn't easy to use and many commands are not allowed in the argument. I would suggest to use lualatex and the new lua-ul package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul}
\colorlet{r1}{ForestGreen}
\colorlet{r2}{RubineRed}
\colorlet{r3}{RoyalPurple}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{r1}
\begin{document}
 \highLight{Forestgreen}, \highLight[r2]{RubineRed}
 It successfully changes the text color to my defined colors.
 \highLight[r3]{But this is not what I wanted}. I want to change the text background color.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to mention that the downside of this is that it cannot be used for papers submitted to the arXiv.

Comment: Looks like I dont have `lua-ul` package. Could you educate me how to install this package>

Comment: You need a current texsystem. miktex (fully updated) or texlive 2020. Don't try to install it manually in an older system, it relies on a current luatex and luacolor version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\colorbox{}{}`:

```
\documentclass{...}
...
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
\begin{document}
    ...
    \colorbox{r1}{ForestGreen}. \colorbox{r2}{RubineRed}
    It successfully changes the highlight color to my defined colors.
    ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Also, when posting an answer, please ensure your code is complete and compilable